Load the configmap changes into the code dynamically in Micronaut without pod restart
I want to load the config changes into the pod and start using it without pod restart in Micronaut. I have created a sample application to try this out. Used Minikube to the test the changes.
Created 2 simple classes along with the Application.java
DummyConfiguration.java
@Refreshable
@ConfigurationProperties("dummy-configuration")
public class DummyConfiguration {
    private String color;

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

ConfigResource.java
@Controller("/config")
public class ConfigResource{

    private final DummyConfiguration dummyConfiguration;

    public ConfigResource(DummyConfiguration dummyConfiguration) {
        this.dummyConfiguration = dummyConfiguration;
    }

    @Get("/color")
    public String getColor() {
        return "The color is: " + dummyConfiguration.getColor();
    }
}

Application.java
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:18-alpine

EXPOSE 8080

COPY target/k8s-0.1.jar /etc/configdemo.jar
COPY target/classes/application.yml /etc/configuration/


WORKDIR /etc

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dmicronaut.config.files=file:/etc/configuration/application.yml", "-jar", "configdemo.jar"]

configmap.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: k8s-config
data:
  bootstrap.yaml: |
    kubernetes:
      client:
        config-maps:
          watch: true
        config:
          enabled: true
          namespace: default

  config.yaml: |
    micronaut:
      application:
        name: k8s
      config-client:
        enabled: true

    dummy-configuration:
      color: white

And mounted the configmap.yml to the deployment.yml
Deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: k8s
          image: k8s:1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          env:
            - name: MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES
              value: "/etc/configuration/bootstrap.yml,/etc/configuration/application.yml"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/configuration
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: k8s-config

According to the micronaut ideally the code also should start populating the new values which isn't happening(https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kubernetes/snapshot/guide/). I have changed the color in the configmap and then applied it which isn't reflecting when I am calling the api.
I am new to Micronaut. Not sure what am I missing out. Thanks in Advance.

In your dockerfile did you miss file name or is it on purpose. Just curious if you need to add filename COPY target/classes/application.yml /etc/configuration/application.yml

yeah it was intentional. I think it won't matter right.

Changes to a ConfigMap are not reflected in running pods (they need to be restarted).
I have used a container called configbump as a sidecar to solve this problem in the past. Basically, instead of mounting the ConfigMap as a volume, configbump will watch the ConfigMap through the kubernetes api and be notified of changes, and then reload those changes. The main container can see those changes when the main container and the sidecar share a emptyDir volume.
Here is a sidecar deployment example.
